# Rename all files in folder to uppercase with batch

Tags: file, batch-file, file-management

Is there a way to rename all files in a specific folder to uppercase with batch file?
I found this code. But it renames files to lowercase. How to modify it to rename to uppercase instead?

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %f in ('dir /l/b/a-d') do (rename "%f" "%f")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

pushd c:\some_dir

for %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~f"

   for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%A=%%A!"
   )
    ren "%%f" "!filename!" >nul 2>&1
)
endlocal
```

Comment: it is not working with mov files, any ideas @npocmaka?

Comment: @rikket - it will work with windows server.Are the mov files read only?

Comment: @rikket - and are these .mov files contains special symbols in their names line `!`

Comment: Yes some of them, with underscore (_)

Comment: @rikket - underscore should be not a problem.Rather it's in the file permissions...

Comment: What error messages do you get when trying to rename MOV files?

Comment: What if I wanted to use this but not make the extension upper case?

Comment: @cusman  try with `set "filename=%%~nf"` right after the first for and `ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"` in the last line

Answer (score 2):

This will put the extension to upper case as well.... Which was a problem for me... So this how I "kept" extension as lower case...

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

pushd "\...\PATH_TO_FOLDER\"

for %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~f"

   for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%A=%%A!"
   )
    ren "%%f" "!filename!" >nul 2>&1
)

for /r "\...\PATH_TO_FOLDER\" %%G in (*.PDF) do ren "%%~G" *.pdf

endlocal
```

replace \...\PATH_TO_FOLDER\ with your path and .PDF/.pdf with your file extention as needed.

Comment: easier: `set "filename=%%~nf"` and later `ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf" >nul 2>&1`. No need for your `for /r` loop. Explanation_ `%%~nf` gives the name without the extension, `%%~xf` is the extension only.

Answer (score 1):

This will convert all filenames in a directory to uppercase without affecting the extension.

```
rename 's/^([^.]*)\.(.*)$/\U$1\E.$2/' *
```