# recursively rename files AND subfolders in a folder using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I know there are similar posts, but non covers what I need.
I need to rename all the files and sub folders of a given folder and make them uppercase. I found this post which is great but only does the files OR subfolders:

[Rename all files in folder to uppercase with batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199066/rename-all-files-in-folder-to-uppercase-with-batch)

I tried doing nested FOR with no joy. According to the manual, /R is suppose to recur through folders, but it is not doing anything. Tried /D /R with no luck either. So I was hoping to use something like below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

pushd C:\MyFolder

for /R /D %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~f"

   for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%A=%%A!"
   )
    ren "%%f" "!filename!" >nul 2>&1
)
endlocal
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Parse a static list `dir /B /S *` to get all files **and** subfolders.

Read entire `for /?` for `%%~nxf` explanation.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

pushd C:\MyFolder

for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /S *') do (
   set "filename=%%~nxf"

   for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%A=%%A!"
   )
    ren "%%~f" "!filename!" >nul 2>&1
)
popd
endlocal
```

Read `ren /?` as well:

```
Renames a file or files.

RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.

Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file.
```

Comment: this is beautiful! works like a charm ... I actually did think of printing the list but then got stuck in parsing them!